# Calling stored procedure from one file into another file in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to keep utility functions/stored procedures in one file and call those in my main script in postgres. Is there any way to import those into my main script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions are database objects. they are stored in database. You can store their definitions in script and recreate function before call of course. If that is your plan, consider using `DO` plpgsql code blocks instead.

Calling functions from script is same as calling them in any sql client. I assume you want to run scripts with `psql`? If so just use `psql -c "SQL LINE(S)"` or

```
psql -c <<EOF
SQL LINE;
SQL LINE;
...
EOF
```

or the best choise if you have script: `psql -f script.sql`